# ui router not loading the views in rawgit but works locally

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is the repository:

https://github.com/vipul-verma/naysa

If you download it and run locally it works.

This is the preview page:

https://rawgit.com/vipul-verma/naysa/master/index.html

Problem :
Rawgit.com only diplays menu it is not loading the views from slider and about page.

Any solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Your templateUrls are absolute so it fails loading when the url isn't root (so on rawgit). It try to load `https://rawgit.com/partials/slider.html` instead of `https://rawgit.com/vipul-verma/naysa/master/partials/slider.html`.

Try changing

```
views: {
  'viewSlider' : {
    templateUrl: "/partials/slider.html"
  },
  'viewAbout' : {
    templateUrl: "/partials/about.html"
  }
}
```

to

```
views: {
  'viewSlider' : {
    templateUrl: "partials/slider.html" // <- remove slash on start
  },
  'viewAbout' : {
    templateUrl: "partials/about.html" // <- remove slash on start
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir for early reply..silly mistake but never thought of that thank you